# replace s01e01 in filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a list of movies that when the link has focus sends the link text to an input field that I use for a search function.
I would like to do the same for TV shows.

My files are currently formatted as

```
<a href="showname s01e01.mp4">Showname s01e01</a>
```

The text I need to send to the input field is

> Showname&Season=01&Episode=01

Is this possible without changing the link text that is displayed on the screen?

This is the script that I use to send the text to the input field.

```
$(function () {
    $('#rightbox a').on('focus', function () {
        var text = $('#moviename');
        text.val($(this).text());
var fileName =$(this).text();
        fileName = fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
        text.val(fileName);    
        $Form.click();
    });
});
```

I'm guessing I need some regex in here, but I'm not good enough at regex yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do it like this to capture both movies and shows titles:

[*updated*]

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c37ha937/2/)**

```js
$("#containera a").click(function() {
  var title = $(this).text(),
    // we check if the title has case insensitive s01e01 pattern
    // if yes it's a show, otherwise it's a movie
    isShow = (/s(\d+)e(\d+)/i).test(title),
    rgx, rplcment;

  // the regex and the replacement both depend on if it's a show or a movie
  // we control it using the conditional (ternary) Operator
  rgx = (isShow) ? / s(\d+)e(\d+).*/i : /(\w+(\.\w+)*)\.\w+/;
  rplcmnt = (isShow) ? '&Season=$1&Episode=$2' : '$1';

  title = title.replace(rgx, rplcmnt);
  $('#moviename').val(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='moviename' size=50>
<div id="containera">
  <a href="#">rocky.mp4</a><br>
  <a href="#">rambo.avi</a><br>
  <a href="#">some #movie [title] & with (dots), w3.2.5.avi</a><br>
  <a href="#">lost s01e01.mp4</a><br>
  <a href="#">simpsons s01e02.mkv</a><br>
  <a href="#">big bang theory S02E05 [lorem ipsum] by ABC123.mp4</a><br>
  <a href="#">some $other show title 3.5 S11E15.mkv</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I've implimented the code in my project. Got a couple of little bugs I didn't think about. Can it be case insensitive? s01e01 and S01E01? Also can it ignore evertything after the s01e01 bit? Thank you again

Comment: Sure, just add a case insensitive **`i`** flag right after the closing **`/`** of the regex both in **`isShow`** check and **`rgx`**, I've updated the answer and the fiddle to do that as well as capturing some movie/show names with dots

Comment: that works great! I found out about the i flag from searching around, but didn't know where it should go. If it's not too much to ask how do I go about ignoring everything after the s01e01?

Comment: Do you mean that if you have "*just a title S02E05 abc 123.mp4*" you want the output to be ""*just a title S02E05*" ?

Comment: yes that's what I'm looking for so if the file is called "someshow s01e01 episode name", I'd like to get someshow&series=01&episode=01

Comment: Ok, that's easy, just replace the regex **`/ s(\d+)e(\d+)\.\w+/i`** with **`/ s(\d+)e(\d+).*/i`**, check the "*big bang theory*" item in the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If your string is as simple as:  'Showname s01e01' then you could use a simple capture of:

`/^(.+?) s(\d+)e(\d+)$/` 
That is:

```
  (.+?)  - Match and capture one or more characters up to a space before
  s      - an s
  (\d+)  - capture the next one or more digits
  e      - followed by e
  (\d+)  - capture the next one or more digits
```

And from those captures you can construct your new string for the input box.

```
$(function () {
    $('#rightbox a').on('focus', function () {
        var filename = $(this).text(); // like "Lost s01e02" ?? 
        var myRegexp = /^(.+?) s(\d+)e(\d+)$/;
        var match = myRegexp.exec(filename); // array of matched bits
        var qryStr = match[1] + '&Season=" + match[2] + "&Episode=" + match[3];
        $("#moviename").val(qryStr); // <- text box??    
        $Form.click();
    });
});
```

input 'moviename' would then contain the string:
*Lost&Season=01&Episode=02*

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m7qxsf6m/4/

Comment: I just tried that, but I can't get it to work. I set up a jsfiddle if you have the time to have a quick look. [link]https://fiddle.jshell.net/tlm2408/Ltv1q84p/  sorry bit of a noob at this.

Comment: You have syntax or some error in your fiddle - but also you don't have the links inside containera - so they won't be found with `$("containera a")`. Also, some of your filenames won't match because they have the wrong format. See my updated fiddle. You will need a different pattern and string concatenation routine for other file name patterns.

Comment: Sorry had a dumb moment there. This works great for episodes. Is it possible to get it to work with movie names as well? The rest of the files are just the movie name and extension eg. rambo.avi. I just need to strip the file extension. Thank you so much for your time and effort.